# Count unique string in a character column

Tags: r, text, count, strsplit

I have a column that has string observations and I need to count the unique words in that column. For e.g.

[image]

I would like my final output to look like this-

[image]

The words in the column are separate using blanks so that is another challenge in my case.

Thanks

Comment: You should look at `strsplit` and `table`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution.

```
# the data
dat <- data.frame(X = c("Program Manager", "Program Coordinator",
                        "Senior Manager", "Senior Associate",
                        "Senior Researcher"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# count words  
table(unlist(strsplit(dat$X, " +")))
```

The result:

```
  Associate Coordinator     Manager     Program  Researcher      Senior 
          1           1           2           2           1           3
```

With `as.data.frame` the result can be converted to  a data frame.

```
tab <- table(unlist(strsplit(dat$X, " +")))
as.data.frame(tab)
```

The result:

```
         Var1 Freq
1   Associate    1
2 Coordinator    1
3     Manager    2
4     Program    2
5  Researcher    1
6      Senior    3
```